# Populating 2d matrix with tokens C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have been struggling all day to figure out how to populate tokens correctly with an input file of a format like:

```
0  0/0d  1/0d  2/1s  3/3s  4/2s  5/2s  6/5s  7/4s  8/4s  10/9d
1  0/9d  1/9d  2/1s  3/1s  4/1s  5/1s  10/9d
2  0/9d  1/9d  3/2s  4/2s  5/2s  10/9d
```

I need to populate the 2d array as thus.

Here is my attempt:

```
char buf[256];
char *tm[10][10];
char * token;
int assign = 0;

while(fgets(buf, 256, file) != NULL){

    token = strtok(buf, " ");

    if(strlen(token) == 1)
    {
            row = atoi(token);
            while(token != NULL){
                    if(strlen(token) != 1 && assign < size+1){
                        tm[row][assign] = token;
                        assign++;
                    }
                    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }

    }
    assign = 0;
}
```

I am able to populate the fields, but things get overwritten, and the index has the last accessed value.

This doesn't make sense to me since if I print out each index as I assign it in a print statement like `printf("%d %d %s\n", row, assign, tm[row][assign]);` I will get the correct output. It's when I leave the while loop that everything gets messed up.

Comment: `tm[row][assign] = token` just stores a pointer in the `tm` array. That pointer points to some part of `buf`. As soon you call `fgets` again, `buf` gets overwritten, and whatever that pointer was pointing to also gets overwritten.

Comment: You are assigning the *address* held by `token` to `tm[row][assign]`. `token` will always point to the last token. Since you have assigned `token` to every `tm[row][assign]` -- they all point to the last token assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must manually allocate memory for your matrix elements, storing the address of the allocated memory in the matrix and copying each token to the associated memory block:

```
char buf[256];
char *tm[10][10];
char * token;
int assign = 0;

while(fgets(buf, 256, file) != NULL){

    token = strtok(buf, " ");

    if(strlen(token) == 1)
    {
            row = atoi(token);
            while(token != NULL){
                    if(strlen(token) != 1 && assign < size+1){
                        tm[row][assign] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
                        strcpy(tm[row][assign], token);
                        assign++;
                    }
                    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }

    }
    assign = 0;
}
```

Remember to free all the allocated memory when you're done with your matrix.

Comment: Good answer even though this question is a dup many times over. Still worth the uptick.

Comment: Thank you!! I recently only dabbled into pointers, I didn't realize I was referring back to the same address, I thought I was creating new addresses as I go on.